# how do I add search capability to my list view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter, android-search

I am planning to add search to my contacts lists I am working on. I added the searchview textchanged listener, how do I go about this so I can get my search working based on letter of each item in my listview? as in what am i missing?

```
enum LvType {
    HEADER_GROUP,
    HEADER_UNGROUPED,
    HEADER_twoway_CHAT,
    HEADER_MANAGED_CHATROOM,
    ITEM_CHATROOM,
    ITEM_twoway_CHAT,
    ITEM_USER,
}
class ListItemsHolder {
    private ArrayList<String>        lvJids;
    private ArrayList<String>        lvNames;
    private ArrayList<Presence>      lvPresences;
    private ArrayList<LvType>        lvTypes;

    public ListItemsHolder() {

    }

    public void init() {
        lvTypes     = new ArrayList<LvType>();
        lvJids      = new ArrayList<String>();
        lvNames     = new ArrayList<String>();
        lvPresences = new ArrayList<Presence>();
    }

    public int setInfo(String jid, String name, LvType type, Presence presence) {
        lvJids.add(jid);
        lvNames.add(name);
        lvTypes.add(type);
        lvPresences.add(presence);

        return lvJids.size();
    }

    public String getJid            (int pos) { return ((lvJids      == null) ? null :  lvJids.get(pos)    ); }
    public String getName           (int pos) { return ((lvNames     == null) ? null : lvNames.get(pos)    ); }
    public LvType getType           (int pos) { return ((lvTypes     == null) ? null : lvTypes.get(pos)    ); }
    public Presence getPresence       (int pos) {   return ((lvPresences == null) ? null : lvPresences.get(pos)); }

    public int getSize() {  return (lvJids  == null) ? 0 :  lvJids.size(); }

}
public class ContactFragment extends RMBaseFragment<MethodsForContactFragment>  implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener, ContactInterface,FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener
        , OnClickListener, OnMenuItemClickedListener, Dialog.OnDismissListener,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
        MainActivity.BackPressListener<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>
{

    public final static String TAG_Contact_FRAGMENT = "TAG_Contact_FRAGMENT";
    private static final String MY_PRESENCE_DIALOG_FRAGMENT = "MyPresenceDialogFragment";
    private RecyclerView m_recycler;

    public static ContactFragment newInstance(final FragmentManager manager) {
        final ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
        final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_Contact_FRAGMENT);

        fragmentInfo.setActionBarTitle("contact list");

        fragmentInfo.setAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        fragmentInfo.setPopAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.no_animation2);
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    private int numOfConferences = 0;
    private int numOfLegacyChats = 0;
    private int numOfGroups      = 0;
    private int numOfUnfiled     = 0;
    private Vector<BookmarkedConference> mConferences = null;
    private Vector<BookmarkedConference> mLegacyChats = null;
    private String[] ContactGroupsNames = null;
    private TreeMap<String, ContactGroup> treeMapOfContactGroups = null;
    //return new TreeMap<String, ContactGroup>(groups).keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    EditText inputSearch;

    private int numOfBookmarks = 0;
    private Vector mBoomarks = null;



    private ListItemsHolder listItemsHolder = new ListItemsHolder();
    private static final String twowayChatsHeader   = "twoway Chats";
    private static final String managedChatroomsHeader = "Managed Chatrooms";
    private static final String ungroupedContactsHeader= "Ungrouped Contacts";

        private MenuHelper mMenuHelper;
    private final ArrayList<String> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ImageView mContextMenuButton;
    private ImageView mMyPresenceButton;
    private FontTextView mMyPresenceTextView;
    private ImageView mContactAccountButton;

    private static class MenuItems{
        final static String PRESENCE = Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.rm_news_menu_presence);
        final static String LOGOUT = Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.rm_news_menu_logout);
        static final int PRESENCE_POSITION = 0;
        static final int LOGOUT_POSITION = 1;
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        mMenuItems.add(MenuItems.PRESENCE);
        mMenuItems.add(MenuItems.LOGOUT);
        mMenuHelper = new MenuHelper(getActivity(),mMenuItems,this,this);
    }

    public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
          private final Activity context;
        private ItemFilter mFilter;

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Activity context) {
            this.context = context;
            prepareDataForListView();
        }
        private int total;

        private void sortDataDefault(wrapper dw) {

            if (dw == null)
                return;

            Contact Contact = dw.getContact();
            Hashtable ht;
            Vector<ContactEntry> entries;
            if (Contact != null && ((ht = Contact.getGroupsEx()) != null) ) {
                numOfGroups = Contact.getGroupCount();
                treeMapOfContactGroups = new TreeMap<String, ContactGroup>(ht);
                ContactGroupsNames = treeMapOfContactGroups.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);

                for (int ii = 0; ii < numOfGroups; ii++) {

                    listItemsHolder.setInfo(ContactGroupsNames[ii], ContactGroupsNames[ii], LvType.HEADER_GROUP, null);

                    ContactGroup group = Contact.getGroup(ContactGroupsNames[ii]);
                    entries = group.getEntriesEx();
                    Collections.sort(entries, comparatorContactEntryAlpha);

                    Iterator<ContactEntry> it = entries.iterator();
                    ContactEntry tmpEntry;
                    while(it.hasNext()) {
                        tmpEntry = it.next();
                        listItemsHolder.setInfo(tmpEntry.getUser(), tmpEntry.getName(), LvType.ITEM_USER, Contact.getPresence(tmpEntry.getUser()));
                    }
                }
                }

            entries = Contact.getUnfiledEntriesEx();
            if (entries != null) {
                listItemsHolder.setInfo(ungroupedContactsHeader, ungroupedContactsHeader, LvType.HEADER_GROUP, null);

                Collections.sort(entries, comparatorContactEntryAlpha);
                Iterator<ContactEntry> it = entries.iterator();
                ContactEntry tmpEntry;
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    tmpEntry = it.next();
                    listItemsHolder.setInfo(tmpEntry.getUser(), tmpEntry.getName(), LvType.ITEM_USER, Contact.getPresence(tmpEntry.getUser()));
                }
            }

            mConferences = dw.getConferences(); 
            if (mConferences != null && mConferences.size() > 0) {

                listItemsHolder.setInfo(twowayChatsHeader, twowayChatsHeader, LvType.HEADER_twoway_CHAT, null);

                Collections.sort(mConferences, comparatorBookMarksAlpha);
                Iterator<BookmarkedConference> it = mConferences.iterator();
                BookmarkedConference bk;
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    bk = it.next();
                    listItemsHolder.setInfo(bk.getRoomId(), bk.getName(), LvType.ITEM_twoway_CHAT, null);
                    }
                }

            mLegacyChats = dw.getLegacyChats(); // mUNitroChatManager.getConferenceBookmarksAsVector(Bookmarks.Type.LEGACY_ROOM);
            if (mLegacyChats != null && mLegacyChats.size() > 0) {

                listItemsHolder.setInfo(managedChatroomsHeader, managedChatroomsHeader, LvType.HEADER_MANAGED_CHATROOM, null);
                Collections.sort(mLegacyChats, comparatorBookMarksAlpha);
                Iterator<BookmarkedConference> it = mLegacyChats.iterator();
                BookmarkedConference bk;
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    bk = it.next();
                    listItemsHolder.setInfo(bk.getRoomId(), bk.getName(), LvType.ITEM_CHATROOM, null);
                }
            }
            }
        private void prepareDataForListView() {

            numOfConferences = numOfLegacyChats = 0;
            mConferences = null;
            mLegacyChats = null;
            listItemsHolder.init();


            try {
                sortDataDefault(controller.getContactModel());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

            }


        }
          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              View rowView = convertView;
              // reuse views
              if (rowView == null) {
                  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_poc_rowlayout, null);
                  // configure view holder
                  ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                  viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);

                  viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                                      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
              }

              // fill data
              ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
              String jid = listItemsHolder.getJid(position);
              String name = listItemsHolder.getName(position);
              holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


              switch (listItemsHolder.getType(position)) {

                  case ITEM_USER:

                      Status status = MessengerUtils.presence2Status(listItemsHolder.getPresence(position));
                      if (status == Status.AVAILABLE)
                          holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
                      else if (status == Status.BUSY)
                          holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.busy);
                      else if (status == Status.AWAY)
                          holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.away);
                      else
                          holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);

                      break;
                  case ITEM_twoway_CHAT:
                      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.twoway_chat);
                      break;
                  case ITEM_CHATROOM:
                      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.chatroom);
                      break;
                  case HEADER_GROUP: // fall thru
                  case HEADER_twoway_CHAT: // keep falling
                  case HEADER_MANAGED_CHATROOM:
                      holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      break;
                  default:
                      //TODO Throw some nasty exception
                      break;
              }
              if (name != null && name.length() > 1){
                  holder.text.setText(name);
                  ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.text.getLayoutParams();
                  params.leftMargin = 20;

              }else
                    holder.text.setText(jid);
              return rowView;
          }


        public String firstUpper(String text) {
            return (text.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (listItemsHolder == null)
                return 0;
            return listItemsHolder.getSize();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null; // don't really need it
            }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Set up search view
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_messenger);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View arg1, final int position, final long id) {
        if (listItemsHolder == null) // paranoia
            return;

        String jid  = listItemsHolder.getJid(position);
        String name = listItemsHolder.getName(position);
        LvType type = listItemsHolder.getType(position);

        if (type == LvType.ITEM_USER) {
            controller.openChat(jid, name);

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        }

    }



    private ListView listView_Contact;
    private TextView empty_tv; 

    private MySimpleArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poc_Contact_fragment, container, false);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_messenger);
                    m_recycler = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerConversations);
        m_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        m_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        m_recycler.setAdapter(m_recyclerAdapter);

        listView_Contact    = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_Contact);
        empty_tv           = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.empty_tv);
        inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_text_messenger);



        mAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity());
        listView_Contact.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        listView_Contact.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView_Contact.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView_Contact.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        //headerView = (HeaderView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_categories_container);
        mContextMenuButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_menu_button);
        mContextMenuButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mMyPresenceButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_presence_button);
        mMyPresenceButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mMyPresenceTextView = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_presence_textview);
        mMyPresenceTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        setMyPresenceStatus();

        mContactAccountButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Contact_contact_button);
        mContactAccountButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        createMenu();
        return view;
    }

    public void chatMessageReceived(BaseNitroChat chat) {
        String from = chat.getName();
        String says = chat.getLastMessage().getBody();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + from + " says " + says, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void ContactModelUpdated() {
        if (mAdapter == null)
            return;

        mAdapter.prepareDataForListView();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        m_recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    }

            @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: You need to implement filter inside your adapter class.

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191000/searchview-that-filters-a-listview-with-custom-listview-items/32191169#32191169

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22330105/1848929